# What is a good tool for unit testing javascript in a maven webapp / liftweb project?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, maven-2, web-applications, lift

I want to unit test the javascript I have embedded in the webapp portion of my liftweb project.  Liftweb is a subset of the maven webapp archetype, so my question applies to that framework as well.

By 'good', I mean that the tests can be integrated into the maven automated testing.

I understand that different browsers support different versions of ecmascript, so I am okay with a testing solution that restricts itself to one specific version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSUnit](https://github.com/pivotal/jsunit) might help with JavaScript testing.

Comment: This appears to test javascript under src/main/javascript, not under the src/main/webapp.  Is that easy to change?

Comment: @Fred According to the above link, the default source directory seems to be `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/js`

Answer (score 0):

I like [QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit) for testing javascript.  I have no idea how well it fits in with the maven test automation tools.  I do know that you can extract the test results in a format that is more friendly to automated builds.

Typical solutions I've seen for including javascript with other forms of automated testing utilize a tool like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [WATiR](http://watir.com/)/[WATiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to fire up a browser and execute the tests.  Of course there is also [TestSwarm](http://testswarm.com/) if you want a way to test javascript against multiple browsers in an automated fashion, but again I am not sure what the capabilities are as far as integrating with other automated testing systems.

Answer (score 0):

Some things that you may find helpful in testing your javascript applications:

- QUnit http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit
- Env.js http://github.com/thatcher/env-js